# Post request body empty - XMLHttpRequest to Express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to access a body from a post request sent using XMLHttpRequest to an express server. However the body of the request is empty and I cannot seem to understand why that is.

I have included a body-parser in the express app, and I have tried to replicate some code from SO answers. But I still get it wrong somehow.

```
<script>
    const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    Http.open('post', 'localhost:3000');
    Http.send("sending something!");// this resolves to {} on the backend?
    Http.onload = function() {
     alert(Http.response); 
    };
</script>
```

This is how I try to handle it on my express server

```
const express = require("express");
let app = express()
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.post("/post", (req, res) => {
    console.log("inside of post");
    console.log(req.body);
})

app.listen(3000)
```

This is the logs

```
inside of post
{}
```

I expect the `console.log()` to print "sending something!" that I try to send with the request with `Http.send("sending something!");`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have specified the `body-parser` to parse the body as url-encoded format which would work if you pass data like this:

```
Http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
Http.send("param1=value1&param2=value2");

/* console output:
{ param1: 'value1', param2: 'value2' }
*/
```

In your case, the data being passed is simple string, which the backend interprets as empty JSON `{}` as it is unable to parse.

For it to work try setting the format of data as follows

```
<script>
    const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    Http.open('post', 'localhost:3000');
    Http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    Http.send("sending something!");
    Http.onload = function() {
     alert(Http.response); 
    };
</script>
```

And in express server:

```
const express = require("express");
let app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
// app.use(
//   bodyParser.urlencoded({
//     extended: true
//   })
// );

app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: "text/plain" })); // use this instead

app.post("/post", (req, res) => {
  console.log("inside of post");
  console.log(req.body);
  return req.body;
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Then you might be able to read the message `"sending something!"` in the backend.
Just make sure you are setting the right contentType header in `XMLHttpRequest` while sending and you use same type while parsing in the backend as well.

For more info on bodyParsers refer this [doc](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#change-accepted-type-for-parsers)

Comment: Nothing short of an excellent answer, thanks a ton. You have really saved me a lot of time!